# How to swap two sets of rows in a table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

I have two sets of rows in a table selected:

```
var slice1 = $( table ).children( "tr" ).slice( i - rowsPerItem, i );
var slice2 = $( table ).children( "tr" ).slice( i, i + rowsPerItem );
```

Which I can highlight using css and verify are the correct rows. Now I want to swap their position in the parent table as a set. They two sets are always one after the other in the table and contain the same number of rows.

Everything I've tried only moves one row:

```
$( slice1 ).after( slice2[slice2.length-1] );
```

How do I keep the sets or rows together, in the same order, but swap their position in the table?

Here's an example of what I'm seeing: http://jsfiddle.net/5vBfA/

Comment: Can you provide a demo?

Comment: @undefined I added a jsFiddle example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `insertAfter` method:

```
$("#SwapButton").click(function () {
    var i = 2;
    var rowsPerItem = 2;
    var $tr = $("#TheTable").find('tr');

    var $slice1 = $tr.slice(i - rowsPerItem, i);
    var $slice2 = $tr.slice(i, i + rowsPerItem);

    $slice1.insertAfter($slice2[$slice2.length - 1]);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/P2vSK/1/

Comment: Could have swore I tried that, but I guess not. That works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
$(".anyOtherTableRow").after(slice1).after(slice2);
```

Comment: If I use that line of code literally, I get the same incorrect result as before.